# Ethernet not detected Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet

Here is the output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 4653  bytes 433590 (433.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4653  bytes 433590 (433.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx34e894d6ef11: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.86.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.86.255
    inet6 fe80::e7d2:d7bc:ea13:327  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 34:e8:94:d6:ef:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 737205  bytes 1091181187 (1.0 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 148  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 334745  bytes 34779005 (34.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the output of `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Here is the output of `ethtool eth0`:

```
Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available
```

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d1200000-d121ffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:12
   logical name: wlx34e894d6ef11
   serial: 34:e8:94:d6:ef:11
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.86.40 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Here is the output of `sudo lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0d4c
       Subsystem: Dell Device 09a6
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
       Memory at d1200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
       Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
       Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4c]
       Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:09a6]
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5405]
       Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:0100]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it a desktop or server? Did Ethernet work before?

Comment: this is a desktop. no i just installed ubnutu on this new machine so ethernet never worked before either

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`. Most likely the kernel doesn't support the adapter.

Comment: The device is not supported by the kernel.

Comment: added the response of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Install Ubuntu 20.04.2 or 20.10 and it should work.

Comment: Your solution on the other question you referenced worked! thanks!